# I get Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon when trying to run docker command

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-machine

I have a docker jenkins running on a server. The operating system is ubuntu.

In the shell when I run:

```
 sudo docker version
```

I get:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea838
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:50:12 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

It is really frustrating. I tried removing and reinstalling docker by adding the following:

```
export RUNLEVEL=1
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce  
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce 
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
#sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

sudo docker version
```

but I get these errors:

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

when I run ps -fe | grep docker:

I get :

```
jenkins 212 207 0 17:57 pts/0 00:00:00 grep docker
```

I also tried the follwoing:

```
#sudo df -h
#sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc

#export RUNLEVEL=1
#dpkg -l | grep -i docker
#sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce  
#sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce 
#sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
#sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
#sudo groupdel docker
#sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
#sudo apt remove docker
#sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
#sudo groupadd docker
#sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)


#sudo apt-get -y purge docker-ce
#sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
#sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo ps -ef | grep docker
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo service docker start
sudo docker version
```

and I see the docker is started:

```
+ sudo service docker stop
 * Docker already stopped - file /var/run/docker-ssd.pid not found.
+ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
+ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker
   ...done.
```

but still I get the same issue:

```
+ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:35:27 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you have explicitly tried to start the docker daemon.

Comment: I added this:  sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker
   ...done. 
but still the same issue

Comment: Is the docker daemon actually running? (`ps -fe | grep docker`)

Comment: @larsks I get this when I run it : + sudo ps -fe
+ grep docker
jenkins     212    207  0 17:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep docker

Comment: please update your answer with the logs of your starting docker daemon and also the result of the `ps` command

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Please check my updates with thanks

Comment: Please also attach the result of `ps` executed juste before doing `docker version`, maybe your daemon crashed after starting

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel it is already there in the update :). I get this: 
jenkins 212 207 0 17:57 pts/0 00:00:00 grep docker